# VB.NET Module - Can I force the use of <Module_Name>.Public_Member_Name when accessing pub. Members?

Tags: .net, vb.net, permissions, module

I have a situation where I have several VB.NET Modules in the same Logical-Module of a large application.

I would like the update function of each module to be public, but I would like users to be forced to qualify the function call with the module name.

```
ModuleName.Update()
```

instead of

```
Update()
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Just make it a Class, with `Shared` members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The VB.NET specifications automatically use [Type Promotion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/type-promotion) to allow this behavior to occur.  The only way to avoid this is to have a type at the namespace that has the same name (Update) which would prevent (defeat) the type promotion provided in VB.NET.

Comment: Reed, you know a lot of stuff. I'm glad, because I like learning. Thanks for your answers today.

Answer (score 2):

Using modules is usually a poor design, because its methods become visible directly in the name space.

Consider replacing them with Classes. Put `Shared` on all the members:

```
Class ClassName
    Public Shared Property SomeData As Integer

    Public Shared Sub Update()
    End Sub
End Class
```

`Update` would be referenced as:

```
ClassName.Update()
```

Make it impossible to instantiate, by having a Private instance constructor (is NOT `Shared`):

```
Private Sub New()
End Sub
```

Any needed class instantiation can be done like this:

```
Shared Sub New()
    ... code that runs once - the first time any member of class is accessed ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Shout it from the rooftops @user113476

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, if you are willing to wrap the module within a namespace of the same name as the module:

```
    Namespace ModuleName
        Module ModuleName
        ...
        End Module
    End Namespace
```